# Bit will not find modules located within tsconfig's srcDir property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My `bit build` cannot locate various modules and fails:

```
$ bit build
  Command failed: node /Users/me/Documents/repos/my-project/.git/bit/components/compilers/angular/bit.envs/0.2.0/node_modules/ng-packagr/cli/main.js -p ng-package.json -c tsconfig.json
ERROR: button/button.component.ts(13,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/my-service-a.service'.
button/button.component.ts(14,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'app/services/models/'.
etc . . .
```

I am thinking that it cannot find modules that live within `src/app` that are just referenced use `app`, eg:

```
import { IMyInterface } from 'app/services/models/';
```

This works in the project because tsconfig.json contains the property

```
"srcDir": "src"
```

so `app/` within the component actually references `src/app`

However, the first line of the error seems to be the full bit command with some default settings explicitly written out. There is written:

```
-p ng-package.json -c tsconfig.json
```

Well, I have no idea about `ng-package.json`. This is not in my project. But the `tsconfig.json` which contains the `srcDir` property lives at the same level in my project as I ran `bit build` from, so the `-c` argument looks correct.

#### How can I instruct Bit to find modules located within `srcDir`?

<sub>Also, I can't find a tag for Bit, so if anyone can help me out with that, thanks. Further, if any maintainers of Bit read this, I need to tell you that your name is really difficult to Google errors for. It's too short and far too common a word. Any search advice in this area would be welcome.</sub>

Comment: I assume that you have read [this](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/tutorials/bit-angular-tutorial)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yeah of course. Have I missed something in particular there?

Comment: Really, I am not aware of this but just trying to help so you can get the idea. What is this line `import { yourmodule } from '@bit/bit.angular-tutorial.product-list';?
`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale That would be how you import your module once it has been successfully built and exported to the bit registry, and eg, installed on a separate project.